# Issue rendering image using Parcel

Tags: parcel

I am using Parcel to create a basic project. I have a json file with images being fetched from the image folder. In JS, I have a for loop which picks up details from the json file. Parcel renames the images and so, while rendering the name of the image is changed and the display contains no actual image.

```
async function getTimeZoneDetails(e) {
const response = await fetch(endpoint + e.abbr);
const data = await response.json();
let zone = e.zone;
let day = data.dayOfWeek;
let time = data.time;
let date = data.date;
let dst = data.dstActive ? " - DST" : "";
let result =
    "<div class='card'><img src='" +
    e.image +
    "' width='100%' /><div class='card_content'><h2>" +
    time +
    "</h2><h3>" +
    zone +
    dst +
    "</h3><h4>" +
    e.states +
    "</h4></div></div>";
document.getElementById(e.id).innerHTML = result;
return data;
}
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
getTimeZoneDetails(arr[i]);
}
```